# How to convert Spring MultipartFile type to RestEasy MultipartFormDataInput type

Tags: spring, resteasy, multipartfile

Currently I have a RestEasy API that receives a parameter of type MultiPartFormDataInput in a POST request. However there is a new  Spring Controller that we want to use that will leverage this previous RESTEasy Controller i.e. the RestEasy controller will be converted to a regular Spring Service.

My problem is that MultiPartFormDataInput is a RestEasy type and is not working in Spring. Instead I'm using MultipartFile in this Spring Rest Controller that is working perfectly fine.

However now I need to convert this MultipartFile into MultipartFormDataInput so that leverage the existing business logic. How could I do this in Java?

I am sorry if I did not explained myself well, I gave my best, any help will be appreciated.